# c++, How to disable escape sequence in visual studio 2019?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

How to disable escape sequence in visual studio 2019?
I want to write just text with symbols `'\'` without edit all text (`'\'` -> `"\\"`)

Comment: Please explain in detail with a [repro] what the issue is. `'\'` and `"\\"` are literals for different types, the first being incomplete.

Comment: Are you looking for [literal raw string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) `R"(c:\unescaped\test)"`?

Comment: Either use raw [string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) (as shown by @Jarod42) or escape the escape (i.e. use double backslash).